# KeyCloak node js gives CORS Error when accessing the API from React/Angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, keycloak

I have added the keycloak.json file in nodejs

```
{
  "realm": "ABC",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "AppShellService",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "MY_SECRET_KEY"
  },
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "enable-cors": true
}

keycloak configuration in App.js

const Keycloak = require("keycloak-connect");
const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();
const keycloak = new Keycloak({ store: memoryStore });
app.use(
  keycloak.middleware({
    logout: "/logout",
    admin: "/",
    protected: "/keycloakauth"
  })
);
```

in App.js i have created a API 
`app.get("/complain", keycloak.protect(), complaintHandler);`

When am i accessing the '/complain' API from my frontend application am getting CORS ERROR

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/ABC/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=client&state=8c20862c-d8dc-457b-841a-a08a44e567f6&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fcomplain%3Fauth_callback%3D1&scope=openid&response_type=code' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8000/complain') from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: When accessing local APIs from an angular app, you'll need to use a proxy. 

Link: https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d

Your proxy should look something like: `{ "/auth": {"target":"http://localhost:8080", "secure": false}}`

Comment: I have added a proxy.config.json but this is for the server side application right am facing issue when a server side api is called and that api internally redirects to keycloak authentication